# Is it possible to set a custom return type for a class?

Tags: c++, class, return

Is it possible to give a specific return type to a class?

For instance, I would like to make a class called `Sentence`, which is basically a `vector` of strings. Would it then be possible to define it so it has a return value of the `vector` of strings (assuming a vector/array can be a return value) ?

edit: I'm pretty tired right now so excuse my bad description. What I meant was setting it so that you could return the class, and it would return a specific variable inside the class. So I would essentially be making a `Sentence` class which was defacto a `vector` of strings as far as the compiler was concerned, just with some functions added in. That way if I told a function to `return Sentence A` it would return the vector of strings inside the object.

Comment: what do you mean by a return type for a class? methods have returns types.

Comment: Can you clarify? Classes don't have return values. Methods do. What exactly are you looking to do? Can you give an example? (Sorry.)

Comment: well for example could I give the sentence class a return value the way strings have a return value?

Comment: Wait, a string does not "have" a return value. Misunderstanding maybe? Adding _code_ to the question would help us help you.

Comment: but Ik I've used "return string blank" when using getter functions. That's the kind of thing I mean.

Comment: That's true. A getter function is a method. And any method can have any return type. Any function can have any return type. So if you have a sentence class, then it can have many methods, and each of those methods can have whatever return type you want. No restrictions. Does that mean the answer to your question is yes?

Comment: I guess I just misunderstood the process, mb XD

Comment: Maybe a code example of what you want to do in theory would help? It sounds like you've wrapped a `std::vector<std::string>`? To be honest your written description doesn't make a whole lotta sense.

Comment: honestly I figured it out already. I thought maybe I could set my class somehow so if I returned the class it would return a specific value inside the class, like making a class that was essentially a defacto vector of strings, but with a couple extra functions. Ultimately though I just made a getter function, and that solved it.

Comment: `That way if I told a function to return Sentence A it would return the vector of strings inside the object` Conversion operator could do that for you. As long as vector of strings is expected to be returned and you have appropriate conversion set up, it will  be returned as vector of strings.

Answer (score 1):

A class is a type.  It is used to define objects; so it doesn't return anything.

However, you can define a **conversion operator** to convert easily an object of that type into another.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Sentence {
    vector<string> words; 
public: 
    Sentence() : words{} {}     // construct an empty sentence
    void add(string word) {     // add a new word to the sentence
         words.push_back(word); 
    }
    operator vector<string> () {   // convert into a vector of string
        return words; 
   }
};
```

With such a conversion operator you can write code such as:

```
int main() {
    Sentence statement;      // create a sencence
    statement.add("hello");
    statement.add("word"); 

    vector<string> w = statement;   // convert the sentence into a vector

    for (auto& x : w) cout <<x<<" ";  // print the vector elements
    cout <<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

You could event have different conversion operators for different target types.  For example, you could add this one to the class:

```
operator string() { // conversion to string 
    string r{}; 
    for (auto x=words.begin(); x!=words.end(); r+=" ")
        r += *x++; 
    return r;
}
```

You could then use it as follows:

```
string s = statement;  // convert the Sentence into a string 
cout<<s<<endl;
```

**[Online demo](https://ideone.com/KF1ube)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

class Sentence 
{
private:

    std::vector<std::string> words;

public:

    Sentence(std::initializer_list<std::string> l) : words{ l } {}

    operator std::vector<std::string>() // conversion operator
    {
        return words;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    Sentence sentence {"hello", "world", "this", "is", "a", "test"};

    std::vector<std::string> arr = sentence; //indicate that you want it to be treated as array

    for (auto word : arr)
        std::cout << word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/6pq3gE